# jOOQ, Java - how to import generated java files?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I'm in the 4th step of this tutorial:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step4/

I generated files from step 3 and put them in `src` directory in my Java project but it seems that IDE can't find it:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to repeat the steps mentioned in [your workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38190654/521799) every time, you should probably change your jOOQ code generation configuration to generate classes in your desired location:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <generator>
    ...
    <target>
      <!-- use the appropriate location here -->
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
      ...
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sure, I know. Thanks. For me as a beginner in Java that wasn't obvious that I have to put those files in src/main/java. Please consider providing that information in your tutorial :) BTW the jOOQ is awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: [The manual was already updated](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step3/) after seeing your question. Thanks for your nice words!

Answer (score 0):

1. Move `database` directory to src/main/java.
2. Make sure that the package name in moved files is correct.
3. Reload project